# t-test - The Alternative Hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

1) My null hypothesis (H0) is: The size of the board shall not influence the firm's performance.
My alternative hypothesis (H1) is: The size of the board shall have a positive influence on the firm's performance

I have run a t-test in Stata between Board Size and Return on Assets (which, in this case, is my measure of firm performance)

The results look a bit weird. I am unsure which of the alternative hypothesis I am meant to pick. They are as follows:

Ha: diff < 0

Pr(T < t) = 1.0000

or

Ha: diff > 0

Pr(T > t) = 0.0000

I am convinced it should be the first. But doesn't this imply statistical insignificance?

2) My second question actually revolves again around the null/alternative hypothesis. My regression analysis indicates that there is actually a negative relationship between board size and firm performance. Since this means neither my null or alternative hypothesis are correct, does this mean, in my conclusions, I have to produce a second alternative hypothesis? (and call it 'H2', for example?)

Comment: Maybe you can explain why a t test addresses the hypothesis test you pose. I don't see it.  It sounds to me more like you are interested in correlation or simple regression.  Maybe you want to test for significance of a regression slope parameter or a correlation coefficient.. You need to explain what you did in Stata to get those results?

Comment: I am only speculating.  Maybe you are applying a two sample t test.  But these are different variables and probably are not even in the same units.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelChernick. What you have done exactly is not at all clear. Questions here should be independent of software, but you do need to show results and not just allude to them. It is hard to see that board size could be  a binary variable and, if it is, that is a very poor way to use information on board size. Perhaps you are referring to the t statistic associated with a regression coefficient, but we should not have to speculate.

Comment: Are you controlling for other things that influence the performance? Are you accounting for endogeneity? Poor performance may cause downsizing of the boards, for instance. This is a typical corp fin study, you should use the "standard" control variables for this field.

Comment: Thank you for your comments thus far. I have been told to carry out a T-test in order to 'test' the hypotheses by my supervisor. I took their word as the bible. To be frank, I don't know how it is supposed to figure with my work. Perhaps anyone can shed light on its use? I must be thick as I've been researching this for months now.

@Aksakal Regarding endogeneity/heterogeneity, I am also running Panel Data and GMM regressions to account for these. I am also using other explanatory variables including Independence and Risk.

Comment: @MichaelChernick You are correct. In Stata, I've been using a two sample t-test using variables (first variable is Board size; second is RoA). These are in different units in as much as board size is just a simple integer, whilst RoA is a decimal (0 to 1 to indicate a percentage). I take it this means it is not possible to run the t-test for this?

Comment: Stata won't even do a plain t-test comparing two means if there are more than two distinct groups, so (once more) what you've done is obscure to me (and I am a fairly experienced Stata user).

Comment: Advertisement: Opening a thread on Statalist would allow you to post Stata output and be widely understood. But note its requests: use your full real name, give data examples as well as code, and tell Statalist about cross-posting.

Comment: @NickCox I think I know what you mean with the two distinct groups thing. I have another variable (CEO Duality) which is entered either as a 1 or 0. When running CEO Duality and RoA together, the results seem more 'correct' (then again, this could be just my imagination).
 
Thank you for recommending Statlist. I'm thinking my questions are a bit software-specific for here, like you said.

Comment: Statalist remains a possibility, and I am active there, but I think the bigger problem remains that you are alluding to results without showing us any in a form that we can understand. You may, or may not, be jumping between comments on results from quite different analyses. At some point, readers may just decide that your question is too vague to be worth their time unless you can add concrete detail that can be discussed.

Comment: @NickCox Understood. In terms of posting results, should I post what the t-test I did has come up with? Or perhaps one of my outputs from my regression models? Forgive my ignorance. I am generally a qualitative person who has unfortunately been tasked with producing a quantitative paper.

Comment: I can't tell you exactly what you should post because I don't understand what you've done.... But I suggest posting the results of a  `summarize` on any variable being analysed directly and showing us the entire output for commands you're asking about and trying to interpret. If it's too much, we can edit. If it's not enough, we can ask for more.

Comment: OK here goes: 
Summary of Board size (Obs 1,266; Mean 9.162717; Std. Dev.  2.273838; Min 4; Max 19)
Summary of RoA (Obs 1,266; Mean .1113204; Std. Dev. .137345; Min -.8404; Max 1.4461)

And from the 2 sample t-test (unequal variances)
diff = mean(bsize) - mean(roa) 
diff (mean) =  9.051397
diff (std error) = .0640226   
diff (95% conf. int.) =  8.925795  to  9.176998
t = 141.3781
Satterthwaite's degrees of freedom =  1274.23
Ha: diff < 0... Pr(T < t) = 1.0000
Ha: diff != 0 ...  Pr(|T| > |t|) = 0.0000
Ha: diff > 0... Pr(T > t) = 0.0000

Hope this helps.

Comment: **Please put output suitably formatted in an edit to the question.**  However, as @Michael Chernick rightly suspected, your t-test appears to be comparing mean board size and mean ROA; that is fallacious. The variables won't even have the same units. The idea that the mean board size equals the mean ROA is no more meaningful than comparing the mean height of people with their mean systolic blood pressure. A regression of some kind will make more sense.

Comment: (You did say this earlier; to be frank I had difficulty believing you.)

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring a very useful comment regarding the inclusion of control variables and the possible issue of endogeneity, the OP seems to run a simple regression (hopefully using also a constant term) of "Return on Assets" on "Board Size".

Then the t-test tests for the null hypothesis that Board Size does not have a statistically significant effect on Return on Assets. Apply this by specifying the complementary alternative "Board Size has a statistically significant effect on Return on Assets".

*If the null is rejected*, just look at the sign of the coefficient estimate : if it is positive, you have statistical evidence that Board Size affects positively Return on Assets, because you have a statistically significant *and* positive coefficient estimate (which gives the direction of influence). Analogously for the case where the estimate is a negative value.

Comment: If this is right (noting comments on the question), then yet another dimension is the applicability of plain regression to a response or outcome variable that is typically positive and likely to be highly skewed.

Comment: @NickCox That's very interesting and I guess there exists a whole separate discussion on the matter (of which I am unfamiliar). Is there some pointer you can provide (CV threads or literature)?

Comment: I guess that you really are familiar with the idea, but just not recognising my allusion! It's what motivates use of a logarithmic link in generalized linear models to ensure positive predictions.  With a suitably generous definition, it's Poisson regression. http://blog.stata.com/2011/08/22/use-poisson-rather-than-regress-tell-a-friend/ is a favourite way in; non-Stata users can hum their way through the Stata parts while translating freely to their own customary software.

Comment: @NickCox Ah yes, now I recognize the face of the beast. Jensen's inequality making our life harder (and perhaps more interesting?)